# Thinktecture IdentityManager choosing a db schema

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

I recently setup a dev site and am using IdentityServer3 with IdentityManager, both from thinktecture, and IdentityManager is designed to create the database for itself, but can be configured to work with an existing db. I was able to get IdentityManager into a local db I had previously created with the default schema, but I would like to switch it to a new schema.  Basically the question is that I can't figure out how to set the desired schema in the db in IdentityManager and can anyone in here give any insight?

Comment: What user store are you using? Membership Reboot, ASP.NET Identity or have you rolled your own?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this (idsrv3 is very configurable). A common way is to add the MembershipReboot package, subclassing the MembershipReboot factory classes, and then loading your new factories during the idsrv3 startup. You will also need the IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot project, which acts as a go-between between IdentityServer3 and MembershipReboot.

In the visual studio package manager console you add the projects like so:

```
    Install-Package BrockAllen.MembershipReboot  
    Install-Package IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot
```

You can use the idsrv3 samples as an example of how to set up your classes. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples

That will give you the data entities you need. Then to write your entities to a database, add the MembershipReboot.EF project and set up a database connection string that gets passed to your override of the MembershipRebootDbContext() class.

```
   Install-Package BrockAllen.MembershipReboot.Ef
```

The first time you start your identity server, MembershipReboot.EF will use Entity Framework to automatically create your database schema and start writing your entities there.

Hope that gets you started, sorry if it's not what you're asking!